# Json ответ в ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Есть форма регистрации, которая работает с помощью ajax

```
$('.login__form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Registration.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            login: login,
            password: pass1,
            email: email,
            referral: referral
        },
        success: function(res) {

            console.log(res);
            console.log(res.message);
            console.log(res.color);
        },
        error: function() {
            Notification('Error!');
        }

    });
});
```

В файле registration.php прописаны различные проверки на существование почты логина и тд, и соответствующие им оповещения об ошибках, например, если письмо отправлено на почту:

```
if ($mail->send())
                {
                    $message = 'Message Send. Check your E-mail!';
                    $color = 'green';
                    $out = array(
                        'message' => $message,
                        'color' => $color
                    );

                    header('Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8');
                    echo json_encode($out);
                    die;
                }
```

Но команды:

```
console.log(res);
console.log(res.message);
console.log(res.color);
```

Выводят в консоль следующее:

```
{"message":"Message Send. Check your E-mail!","color":"green"}2020-02-29 02:19:47 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: QUIT<br>
undefined
undefined
```

Почему res.message и res.color приходят как undefined?

**UPDATE**
Виновником является phpMailer, удалил все что связано с отправкой сообщения зарегистрированному пользователю и оставил только оповещение об успешном добавлении в БД, в случае успеха. В итоге запись добавилась, и оповещение появилось, как теперь быть с отправкой почты? Может что-то не так в моих настройках мейлера? Вот код:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
                $mail->isSMTP();
                $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
                $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
                $mail->Host = 'mail.domain';
                $mail->Username = 'domain@mail';
                $mail->Password = '';
                $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
                $mail->Port = 587;
                $mail->setFrom('domain@mail', 'domain@mail');
                $mail->addAddress($email);
                $mail->SMTPOptions = array(

                    'ssl' => array(
                        'verify_peer' => false,
                        'verify_peer_name' => false,
                        'allow_self_signed' => true
                    )
                );
                $mail->isHTML(true);
                $mail->Subject = $title;
                $mail->Body = "$messageEmail";
```

Comment: Используйте `$.post`, вместо `$.ajax`. И не придется мучиться с типами и  т. д. И да, если используете `json`, то последним параметром функции `$.post` добавьте аргумент `json`.

Answer (score 1):

**JavaScript:**

```
$.post('Registration.php', {
   login: login,
   password: pass1,
   email: email,
   referral: referral
}, function(res) {
   console.log(res.message);
   console.log(res.color);
}, 'json').error(function() {
   // Error...
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
if ($mail->send()) {
    $message = 'Message Send. Check your E-mail!';
    $color = 'green';
    $out = array(
        'message' => $message,
        'color' => $color
    );
    header('Content-Type: aplication/json; charset=utf-8');
    exit(json_encode($out));
}
```

Comment: Сделал как вы написали, добавил в  function(res) вывод console.log('success'); а в error: console.log('error'). В итоге скрипт отработал верно, но без каких-либо оповещений и выводов в консоль

Comment: @Ayurpwnz, попробуйте убрать `json` из `$.post` последний аргумент.

Comment: убрал, все тоже самое - никаких оповещений

Comment: @Ayurpwnz, ну так вам не помочь к сожалению. Не видно ничего, может быть что угодно и где угодно.Надо тестить смотреть и разбираться, у меня например подобный скрипт без проблем работает. Значит проблема у вас где-то.

Answer (score 0):

Вы возвращаете json, а ожидаете text

Поменяйте dataType: 'text' на dataType: **'json'**

Comment: в таком случае срабатывает событие error, а не success, хотя скрипт registration отрабатывает нормально

Comment: console.log([ xhr.status, textStatus ]) выдает  0: 200
1: "parsererror"

Comment: @Ayurpwnz Я не знаю что оно у вас там выдает, но пока вы получаете text вместо ожидаемого json вы текст и будете получать и console.log(res); это показывает. И заголовок вам судя по всему тоже следует поменять на header("Content-type: application/json");